# appcompat_v7 loads in eclipse when activity create

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

Guys is there any solution for stop adding appcompat_v7 in my project , I just want to update my android application by adding one activity in the project, I am using minimum SDK version 8 and using actionbarsherlock, every time I add any activity elipse add appcompat_v7 , if I remove it I got error , R cannot be resolved to a variable occurs, This folder is too much irritating, I know appcompat_v7 is for actionbar compatibilty with older version, but for my current project it is no use,
Any Idea or solution please share I have already google this issue  and search on stackoverflow nothing working for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of using the convenient add android activity method, create the activity class and layout (and menu) xml files manually, and add the new activity to the manifest file.

Comment: Thanks Haike I am exactly doing the same right now :) as you said , but it is time consuming if I want to add more then one activity , :(

Comment: Check the @commonsware blog -  http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/15/really-blank-activity-why-appcompat-shoved-down-your-throat.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps for resolving this issue

1. Delete `appcompat_v7`(which is generated while u creating ur project) from `eclipse and workspace`.
2. If u want to use `fragment` then the class should be *extends*
   `FragmentActivity` otherwise
   *extends* `Activity` and delete all `Fragment` stufs.
3. After that change `style` from all `styles` files and use native
   `android theme` not any theme from `appcompat`.
4. Change in `menu` folder is needed.See the code snippet

code snippet for style

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
```

code snippet for menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.android.multitaskme.tasker.SplashActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Clean ur project and u r good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem after updating eclipse.

The reason you are getting error after deleting the appcompat_v7 folder is it contains the R.java file which is auto-generated by the ide.
You can check your project gen folder it has no more the R.java file.

For now you can manually add new activity but for larger project if will be very time consuming and boring.
I suggest you keep this as it it.

By the time you will get used to it as myself.